# Spatial Join has Merge Rule Delimiter greyed out

Tags: arcgis-desktop, merge, spatial-join, delimiter

I'm trying to use Spatial Join between a line layer and polygon layer. Where the polygon layer contains Area Names I would like to add to the lines. Sometimes a line will cross more polygons, so I'm thinking of using a Join_One_To_One, with the Merge Rule as Join for names. This works fine however, I would like a delimiter in the Merge Rule, such as a Comma.

However the Delimiter part is greyed out, any suggestions why and how to get around it?

[image]

Comment: Try one to many option as you say many polygons intersect a polyline. The delimiter option may then become available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you must right-click properties and choose the Merge Rule as Join there. If you right click and choose merge rule as join before entering properties it remains greyed out for some reason.

So Right-Click properties and then choose merge rule in there instead of in the Field Map of Join Features window.